# Значение глагола «нарекать»

Tags: грамотная-речь, значение-слов, устаревшие-слова

Объясните, пожалуйста, если слово "нарекание" значит *упрек, попрёк, укоризна*, а слово "нарекать" значит *называть, давать имя*, может ли быть использовано слово *нарекать* со значением *упрекать*? По-русски ли это?

Comment: нарекать - облечь в речь, придать определенное значение поступку или образу. Поэтому нарекание может быть связано с придумыванием, но не имени, а клички.  Кличка - это имя данное другими, а не при крещении и тп., то есть не настоящее имя. Также нарекание может быть с негативным обозначением, вроде наговаривания/оговаривания, сплетни, слуха. Наречь - обвинить в проступке. Я бы связал нарекание с семантикой - то есть это устаревшее слово весьма современное и актуальное.

Answer (score 3):

Глагол *наречь* (*нарекать*) словарь Ушакова (1935–1940) считает книжным, торжественным, устаревшим. В современных словарях такие характеристики: Ожегов — устаревший, Ефремова — разговорный, МАС — устаревший и высокий.

Сегодня его значение таково ([МАС](https://dicipedia.com/dic-ru-ru-academ-term-38454.htm)):
**1.** *Устар.* Назвать, дать имя кому-либо.
**2.** *Устар. и высок.* Назвать, объявить кем-либо, чем-либо.

Если же мы заглянем в словарь Даля (1863–1866), то там имеются такие значения:
[*нарекать*](https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/enc2p/381119), наречь, или малоуп. нарицать, нарещи: твер., пск. нарековать кого или что; называть, именовать; давать имя, названье, зов, кличку;
| кого в чем; что на кого; **наговаривать, обвинять кого, порицать, укорять в чем**. Он во св. крещение наречен Иваном. **Его нарекают в неправде. На него нарекают напрасно.**

Упрекать — это и есть укорять, порицать, пенять, журить.
Я нашла "наш" глагол в этом значении у А. И. Солженицына ("Рассказы и крохотки"):

> И вот тут-то – многие, многие маршалы и генералы кинулись писать свои мемуары и издавать их. И Жуков поражался их взаимной ревности, как они выставляли себя и старались отобрать честь от соседей, а свои неудачи и промахи – валить на них же. Так и Конев теперь строчил (или ему писали?) свои воспоминания – и во всём он чистенький, и безсовестно [sic] перехватывал себе славу достижений скромного и талантливого Ватутина (убитого бандеровцами). **И уж на Жукова, зная, что он беззащитен, кто только не нарекал.** Артиллерийский маршал Воронов дошёл до того, что приписал себе и план операции на Халхин-Голе, и успех её.

*По-русски ли это?* Да. Но устаревшие слова в современной речи требуют осторожного употребления: вы должны быть уверены, что вас правильно поймут. Нет такой уверенности — используйте современные слова, со всем понятным значением.

Еще пример (Василь Быков. Знак беды):

> Как-то перед Рождеством по деревне пошли разговоры, что стали пропадать мясные припасы с чердаков, сначала **нарекали на старого ленивого кота** Корнилы, даже пытались его убить колом из забора и, наверное, убили бы, если бы кот не поспешил взобраться на самую верхушку клена, где и просидел до вечера.